# What is notification's "small icon" mdpi size

Tags: android

For mdpi, it is very clear that notification icon (numbered 2) size should be 24x24

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification

However, how about **small icon**?

[image]

Android design guideline doesn't mention on what is mdpi size for **small icon (numbered 5)**.

Comment: I believe ldpi is just 0.75 the size of mdpi, so 18x18 (24*0.75)

Comment: http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Comment: Where is **ldpi** mentioned in OP's question? He asked for **mdpi** small icon, not **ldpi**.

Answer (score 2):

`Small icon size (status bar AND small icon in extended notification view)`

For **mdpi** (160 dpi, scale factor = 1.0 => 1 dp = 1 px), as you required:

For API Level  8- (8 and older),   the full asset is 25*25 with an optical square of 21*21
For API Level  9+ (9 - 10),        the full asset is 16*25 with an optical square of 16*16
For API Level 11+ (11 and higher), the full asset is 24*24 with an optical square of 22*22

It's the same as the "status bar icon" size.

For reference: http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/
More about that: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

`Big icon`

For API Level 16+ (16 and higher), the full asset is 32*32 with an optical square of 24*24

Comment: My question is small icon (numbered 5 in screenshot)

Comment: Exactly. It's the same as the "status bar icon" size. More about that: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: But for the link you provided, I can't see it talk about small icon numbered 5? They only mention "Notification Icons", which I assume is for icon numbered 2.

Comment: `They only mention "Notification Icons"`. Yes, which means **normal** (= StatusBar) icons. "#5" is what they call "big icon", which is not what you asked for, I suppose.

Comment: Oh, getting confused. I thought #5 is "small icon" ?

Comment: Sorry, I confused #2 with #5 (I'm doing too many things in the same time, damn 24 hrs days!!). Yes it's #5 the small icon and #2 the big icon. So. Notification icons is #5, while #2 is **big icon**

Comment: OK. So, do you know the size of #2 (Big icon)? As all the while, I thought it should be 24x24 ?

Comment: I updated my answer. 24*24 is the **optical square** (the icon itself), while the full asset (icon + "transparent border") is 32*32